# Foundation 6 DropdownMenu Events not Firing

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I'm trying to get an animation to fire when the dropdown is opened, however, I can't seem to attach an event listener. The following code isn't firing, though I can see the classes changing on the dropdown.

```
$('[data-submenu]').on('show.zf.dropdownMenu', function() {
    console.log('open');
});
```

Here is a pen http://codepen.io/thezenmonkey/pen/PGXVRV

Comment: It would be super helpful if you could create a live example using [CodePen](http://codepen.io/) or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: No problem, here you go http://codepen.io/thezenmonkey/pen/PGXVRV

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with codepen to know, but is the foundation.dropdown.js included in your example? It is required to be included according to the docs. Also 3 utilities are required:
http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/dropdown-menu.html

Comment: Yes, the full foundation.js is in the pen. So it shoudl have the plugin as well as the all the utilities. (if you click the gear icon in the JS panel you'll see the external libraries loaded)

Comment: According the foundation docs I shoudl be listening on the [data-submenu] http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/javascript.html#events

Answer (score 3):

Turns there is an error in the current version of the documentation. Listener needs to be attached to the document and the event name is wrong.

```
$(document).on('show.zf.dropdownmenu', function(ev, $el) {
    console.log('open');
});
```

Comment: Wow, I just applied the listener as you did in your code here, it worked just as it should. I agree, the Zurb Foundation 6 documentation is a problem, this is just one more example on the pile. I hope you can accept your own answer as correct!

Comment: BTW... could you add a link/document to where you may have found the correct syntax?

Comment: @ChrisO I looked at the actual Javascript code in foundation.dropdownMenu.js. I've put in pull request with Zurb to correct the documentation. Looks like the docbloc decalring the event hadn't been updated